# Disable WebSocket logging

Tags: logging, websocket, netty

Running a WebSocket application (e.g. WebSocketServer), I am getting plenty of debugging messages like this:

```
18.02.2012 18:35:17 io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocket08FrameEncoder
FEIN: Encoding WebSocket Frame opCode=1 length=20
18.02.2012 18:35:17 io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocket08FrameDecoder
FEIN: Decoding WebSocket Frame opCode=1
18.02.2012 18:35:17 io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocket08FrameDecoder
FEIN: Decoding WebSocket Frame length=16
18.02.2012 18:35:17 io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocket08FrameDecoder
FEIN: Decoding WebSocket Frame opCode=8
18.02.2012 18:35:17 io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocket08FrameDecoder
FEIN: Decoding WebSocket Frame length=2
```

Unfortunately I didn't find a way to deactivate them. Where can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Netty use jdk logging API as its logging engine. This messages are logged via DEBUG loglevel so you just need to setup the logging to not print out debug messages for this class.

Comment: Oh damn... I was running an old version which contained `ConsoleHandler ch = new ConsoleHandler();
        ch.setLevel(Level.FINE);
        Logger.getLogger("").addHandler(ch);
        Logger.getLogger("").setLevel(Level.FINE);`

Answer (score -1):

If you are using log4j logging, just put this line inside your `log4j.properties` file.

```
log4j.logger.io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx = OFF
```